# Definition of relative (line) bundle.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \to S$ be a flat, smooth morphism of schemes. 
How exactly does one rigorously define relative line bundles on $X$? Would these still be parameterized by $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$?

I know the definition of the relative (co)tangent sheaf but I wouldn't know how to extend this to more general relative constructions.